# Pandas sum dataframe but retain shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
    keyboards   lights  candles games
0   100         21      11      20
1   125         12      10      66
2   140         32      42      66
3   110         12      64      55
4   90          10      20      42
5   432         34      20      75
```

All I want to do is sum these values up so that the df looks like:

```
    keyboards    lights    candles    games
0   997          121       167        324
```

When I use .sum() on the dataframe, it seems to pivot the frame and I get:

```
            0
keyboards   997
lights      121
candles     167
games       324
```

Is it possible to sum like this without the pivot?
Thanks!

Comment: you could transpose that result -> ```df.sum().to_frame().T``` which I believe will get you exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Amazing, Works perfectly!

Comment: I think ```df.agg(sum)``` as well would return a series, so you would need to do the same to get to the desired result.

Comment: @sophocles you are right, when called with single function it returns series, but with multiple agg function it returns dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The `.sum` function returns a pandas series which will always be printed vertically.

A possible workaround is to transform the pd.Series to a pd.DataFrame before doing the transpose. The solution would be:

```
df.sum().to_frame().T
```